# SPF record setup ip4 or include

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have two domains (example.com 192.168.0.1 and example.net 192.168.0.2) and I want to allow example.net to send email from foo@example.com

In my SPF I currently have:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:192.168.0.1/32 include:spf-a.outlook.com -all
```

To add the second entry do I add this as ip4:192.168.0.2 or should I use include:example.net or are neither correct in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Which spf record is that? Example.net? Example.com?
The spf record for example.com should contain ip4:192.168.0.2.
Using include would include the whole spf record of the target domain (and fail if there is none), this is probably not what you want.
Of course for production ip should not be private ones.

Comment: This was for example.com - I wasn't sure if I should use the IP or include. Email will never actually come from foo@example.net, all emails will come from the example.net server but will use example.com as the sender address etc

Answer (score 1):

Either are valid, but use `ip4:`.

Outlook.com's SPF records spiral down so deep into DNS lookups that you cannot add [m?]any more `include:` directives without violating SPF's RFC-defined limit. Most SPF validators don't strictly enforce this, but some *do* and can cause deliverability issues at random.